# Read account email with batch

Tags: azure, email, batch-file, network-drive

I am trying to connect every user account at login with our shared storage. 
This works fine with the command in CMD:

```
net use \\NAS /USER:email@domain.com passwordhere
```

As we are using AzureActiveDirectory, I will need an email to connect to our shared storage. How can I read the email of the current user to replace it with the example adress? This all should happen in a batch file as there are also plenty of other lines already written. (Also without admin permissions if possible).

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Are all the user's email aliases the same as their user names on the system? If so, %USERNAME% should work. If not, you could check for a system level environment variable of the form LoggedOnUserEmail and if it doesn't already exist, prompt for it and use `setx` to set it.

Comment: Alternately, you could write the value to a local data file somewhere.